# How to get date where was background event double clicked in Fullcalendar v4?

Tags: fullcalendar, double-click, fullcalendar-4

I have background events in my Fullcalendar, I use timeline view. I added a doubleclick trigger to handle this action, but I need to get date, where was doubleclick done.

For example, if user clicks on highlighted square, it should fire "6th of November was double clicked". (greenline is background event).

[image]

```
eventRender: function(info) {
  $(info.el).on('dblclick', function() {
    // I need to somehow get clicked date here
    alert('XYZ was double clicked!');
  });
});
```

Is here a way how to get the clicked day?

Comment: [The docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender) show that `info` includes the `event`.  So `info.event.start` will give you the start date.

Comment: It gives me start of background event, not the clicked date which I need.

Comment: Oh I see, if you have multi-day events they will be different.

Comment: This isn't possible. Why do you want to do this? What are you planning to do with this date?

Comment: My use case is, that user dblclick to field and pop-up with two dates (from - to) will show up. First date is filled with clicked date and user can select the second date from calendar. After submit is new event created based on filled dates. It is for longer events, for example if they reach to the another month(s). Any other idea how it could be possible?

Comment: For that you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/select-callback - it will let the user drag over the total area they want to select, and give you both the start and end date without them needing to enter any dates manually. But it must be used on an empty area of the calendar where no other events already exist. In your version right now you are trying to create an event on top of another existing event, which isn't supported (and doesn't really make a lot of sense to me, either).

Comment: Creating events by this way I have already implemented, but when user want to create event from one month to another (I have 30 day visible range), he must to create two events in fact. Thats the way I wanted the dblclick solution. About your last sentence, I use background events (I mentioned it in my question above), it is allowed and makes sense. In my case, background events highlight areas I want and in those users can make "stanard" events. I just want to give user chance to make event from one month to another.

Comment: "when user want to create event from one month to another (I have 30 day visible range), he must to create two events in fact"...hm that sounds a bit over-complicated. Why not have it so that the user just clicks to select the start date (or drags to select an area if they do want it all within the visible view), and then you pop up a modal dialog with a datepicker, pre-populate the start/end dates as selected in the calendar, but allow the user to amend them if they want a date further in the future. To me that sounds more user-friendly than all this double-selecting etc. Just my opinion tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the solution up. It is little bit dirty, but it works.

1. I am calculating with mouse click coordinates
2. get the width of day column
3. calculate order of the clicked column
4. by the order of clicked column I get the same column in the header
5. I get the date from `data-date` attribute from the column in header

.

```
$(info.el).on('dblclick', function(event) {
    // get the element of the whole row
    var element = $(this).parent().offset();

    // get the x position of cursor
    var x = event.pageX - element.left;

    // get the width of column, dynamically calculated because width of viewport can be changed
    var width = $('.fc-head .fc-time-area th.fc-widget-header').outerWidth() - 1;

    // order number of clicked column
    var number = Math.ceil(x / width);

    // now we have a date of clicked date (despite we clicked background event)
    alert($('.fc-head .fc-time-area th.fc-widget-header:nth-of-type(' + number + ')').data('date'));
});
```

Maybe it helps somebody. Just notice, this solution counts with background events - these events are clicked.